# Im not getting white this iteration doesent work?

Tags: java

When I output this `album1.findSongInAlbum()` method, no matter what I input I get "not working" or if I enter right name, I get `album song found`, and again also `Not working`.

```
public boolean findSongInAlbum(String songName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.albumContainingListOfSongs.size(); i++) {
        if (songName.equals(albumContainingListOfSongs.get(i).getTitle1())) {
            System.out.println("Album song  found: " + albumContainingListOfSongs.get(i).toString());
        } else if (!songName.equals(albumContainingListOfSongs.get(i).getTitle1())) {
            System.out.println("Not workin");
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

output is supposed to be one or another, either found song, or not found song, but never both.

Comment: It may be because you output "not workin" for every non-match.  You only need to do it once at the end if there were no matches.  I would step through the code in your favourite IDE and see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.

1. If you find a match, you should return true immediately.
2. If you don't find a match, you should stay in the loop, and not return false. Only return false after the loop is done.

This should work:

```
public boolean findSongInAlbum(String songName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.albumContainingListOfSongs.size(); i++) {
        if (songName.equals(albumContainingListOfSongs.get(i).getTitle1())) {
            System.out.println("Album song found: " + albumContainingListOfSongs.get(i).toString());
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Album song not found");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, flawless, thank you so much for the answer!!  that else if was completely unnecesary with return false, it was breaking the loop :/